# Docstrings don't automatically indent themselves in elpy-mode. How do I fix this?

Tags: indentation, python, documentation, elpy

This is an example function that shows that docstrings do not automatically indent.

```
def testing_docstring():
    """
docstring is not indented automatically!
Even after a newline.
"""
    body_is_indented_though
    return
```

Selecting a region inside the docstring and hitting tab won't work either. Only hitting tab on a single line will toggle the indent level. How can I set docstrings to automatically indent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`elpy` has a function `elpy-open-and-indent-line-below` which is binded to `<S-return>`.

After `"""`, you can hit `<S-return>` to open new line and indent automatically. You can use this at the end of line.

Alternatively, you can bind `return` to this function.

```
(define-key elpy-mode-map (kbd "<return>") 'elpy-open-and-indent-line-below)
```